# Resume the app using setPackage method

Tags: android

In my app I having problem regarding launching of any third party app(Messaging,Whats app,etc).I can successfully launch any app by using this code:

```
 Intent intent=getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("your package name");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(intent);
```

The problem is with the above code is that it relaunches the app from start instead of resuming where the user has left it.

So, I have found couple of code in order to work here it is:

```
 Intent i=new Intent();
            i.setPackage("com.android.contacts");
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(i);
```

I think it probably resumes the app but it didn't working properly.I think I had implemented it in a Wrong way,I don't know
Can anyone help me 
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can't
When you create a new intent and put bundle as a argument , you tell the Android System you want to create a new instance of a activity and this is not possible to open the Tasks runned by user . Because google has removed GET_TASK permissions from android.

Comment: Any solution for launching an app and should be resumed where the user has left it.

Comment: I have tried this code 
                `Intent i=new Intent();
                i.setPackage("com.android.contacts");
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                startActivity(i);`         but it always created a new instance on above of my running app .